# In Page Object Model do i have to create webdriver all the time?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, pageobjects

I'm using the Page Object Model I just started i created 2 packages one is com.automation.pages another one is com.automation.testcases.
In both packages I created a class for the login page it works fine I'm sharing the code below.

```
package com.automation.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class LoginPage {
    
    WebDriver driver;

    
    public LoginPage(WebDriver ldriver)
    {
        this.driver=ldriver;
    }
    
    @FindBy (xpath="//input[@name='email'] ") WebElement email;
    @FindBy (xpath="//input[@name='password']") WebElement password;
    @FindBy (xpath="//body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]") WebElement loginbutton;
    
    
    
    public void logintoLabaiik(String email1, String password1 )
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        email.sendKeys(email1);
        password.sendKeys(password1);
        loginbutton.click();
    }
    
    
}
```

The problem I'm facing when I working on the new page is when I created a driver and when using ldriver it throws me an error also when I replace the "l" still it throws me the error. kindly solve my problem.

```
package com.automation.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class TaxSetup {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public TaxSetup(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver.ldriver;
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the below line in your `TaxSetUp` constructor.

`this.driver.ldriver;`

This is suppose to be

`this.driver = driver;`

And yes, you have to pass the `WebDriver` instance for all the page classes that you create as part of your application otherwise they will assign default value to the driver which is `null`.

Comment: Thank You supputuri for your help and time. I'm very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you have an issue in `TaxSetup` constructor.

This should work.

```
public TaxSetup(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
}
```

Take a look at how to create 2 Page Object classes and use them in tests:

**LoginPage**

```
public class LoginPage {
    
    final WebDriver driver;
    
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    // page implementation
}
```

**TaxSetup**

```
public class TaxSetup {
    
    final WebDriver driver;
    
    public TaxSetup(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    // page implementation
}
```

### How to use in test

```
public class SomeTest {

    WebDriver driver;
    LoginPage loginPage;
    TaxSetup taxSetupPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public void initDriverAndPages() {
        driver = ... // e.g. new ChromeDriver()
        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        taxSetupPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, TaxSetup.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // implement test using loginPage, taxSetupPage as you like
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```